# Why amp-video and amp-audio force the usage of https for src?

Tags: amp-html

On the documentation about [AMP-video](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/amp-video.html) this is indicated that:

**src**: Required if no children are present. **Must be HTTPS.**

Why this is needed ?

- Is this for security issue ? (my video and audio doesn't need security).
- Is this for performance (and in this case, since when https is faster than http ?)
- Any other reason ?

From my point of view, that look strange to allow the full AMP technology to work on http and only restrict part of them to https. What is the rational behind that ?

Comment: It was stated that AMP files are eventually served via HTTPS. "All resources that cannot easily be proxied need to be served as HTTPS from the origin." You can see it here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/260

Comment: "eventually" was fine with me, as I used a protocol independent URL ("//domain.com/path"). But since the fix https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/2027, I now can't serve any video in http when my container is in http.

Answer (score 3):

It's a security thing - if/when your content is hosted on Google's CDN, all elements will be served over HTTPS, so standard HTTP elements won't work.

Comment: I'm sure https is for security, what I don't understand it's to force the usage for amp-video:
 - amp-img don't force https and allow CDN the rewrite url if needed.
 - http html5 video can be played by https container

Comment: It's because in the CDN, Google will cache the images on their HTTPS servers; they don't cache the videos, so they must be directly served over HTTPS

Comment: Yes, but they remove the support of protocol independent ( url start with //) that was working in both staging evn (without https) and production (with https).