# Google AMP requires HTTPS for audio?

Tags: audio, amp-html

I'm working on making a client's blog site AMP-friendly and I'm running into an issue with their audio posts. It's just a simple WP site where they are uploading the audio files for the podcasts and I'm running into an issue where it says

> Source must start with "https://" or "//" or be relative and served from either https or from localhost.

I don't see anywhere in their documentation that this is a rule. I have not run into this issue with other media types. Is there a fix other than setting up an SSL for the site?

Comment: you can create free valid TLS certs from letsencrypt which will give you https ... welcome to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no work around. You must use [https](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/validation_errors#invalid-url-protocol) for [Audio](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-audio). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35454551/why-amp-video-and-amp-audio-force-the-usage-of-https-for-src?rq=1) too.

Comment: The reason for this is that the AMP Cache only caches images, not really large files like audio and video. These files will be served from your site directly, and if served over http will generate mixed-mode warnings.